# Getting PowerApps to send the IP address to a SQL database

Tags: android, database, azure-sql-database, ip-address, powerapps

So I have a clocking in app we have developed on Powerapps that is ran on android tablets across multiple sites in the UK, what we want is to get the App to send the public IP address to our SQL database every time someone clocks in.
Would anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Thanks

I have tried looking for information online regarding this but can't find anything anywhere.

Comment: Well what is the problem doing so? I cant image you cannot send some data to that db.

Comment: I'm wondering how to do it, I want to know how to ask Powerapps to pull the public IP address and then send it to the sql database

Answer (score 0):

The DMV sys.dm_exec_connections should have all the info you need for the connections made to the database. Filter by the current session and you'll get its IP address:

```
SELECT session_id, client_net_address FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@SPID
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16